# Convert string to string

Tags: string, go, command-line, converters

please say.
Why string "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81" in the code don't equally "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81" from arguments command line?

```
func main() {

    text1 := "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81"
    text2 := os.Args[1]
}
```

Length string "text1" = 4, "text2" = 16 if len(text1).
How i can convert "text2" to "text1"?

Comment: I know nothing about go but coming from a C# world, `\x` in a string is a *compiler* thing, where the string `"\bx"` consists of two characters, the bell-character and the character `x`. If you want to mimick this when accepting command line arguments, well, then you basically need to mimick this. Your string consists of 16 characters because `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81` is 16 characters, there's no interpretation going on at all.

Comment: You basically have to implement something that runs through the string and converts all the possible escape formats/values into their corresponding characters.

Comment: I understand it, but how? May be there are ready on the golang or somebody know, how i can do it. How it do it to C#, please say.

Comment: There is no support in C# or .NET for doing this, other than the compiler, and obviously writing some code to do it. There might be something in go, but at least you know what the problem is and that should stear you towards the solution (assuming whatever I know about C# is applicable in this situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a standard package and a function for this. [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote)

> Unquote interprets s as a single-quoted, double-quoted, or backquoted Go string literal, returning the string value that s quotes. (If s is single-quoted, it would be a Go character literal; Unquote returns the corresponding one-character string.)

Note that you need to quote the input stirng. In your code, it should be:

```
text2 := strconv.Unquote(`"`+os.Args[1]+`"`)
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/u2yU3VQHhXO